# How do I specify the schema in EclipseLink JPQL query?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

When I execute the query below I get the exception thereafter. How do I specify the schema in a JPQL query. My database schema is public. The database is PostgreSQL.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p FROM profile p WHERE p.mobile_no = :mobileNo
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT p FROM profile p WHERE p.mobile_no = :mobileNo]. 
[14, 21] The abstract schema type 'profile' is unknown.
[30, 41] The state field path 'p.mobile_no' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1746)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1767)
    za.co.ezimax.database.ProfileDAO.get(ProfileDAO.java:15)
    za.co.ezimax.business.Business.register(Business.java:44)
    za.co.ezimax.rest.DatabaseTestServlet.doGet(DatabaseTestServlet.java:87)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I specify the schema in a JPQL query?

The schema configuration doesn't below to the query itself. It's configured in the datasource.

Keep in mind you are actually writing [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) (and not [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)). So you write queries against entities and not against tables. Having said that, you are expected to use the entity name and the entity fields instead of table names and table columns.

Instead of `profile`, you should use `Profile` (capital `P`):

```sql
SELECT p FROM Profile p WHERE p.mobile_no = :mobileNo
```

Also ensure that `mobile_no` is the name of the field in your `Profile` entity (and not the name of the column in your database table).